# Get Authors Randomly

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

how to get authors details and author page permalink randomly. I have checked the new [get_users()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_users) function for wordpress which is returning the author but i can not sorting them randomly.

here is the site i am using the code: http://citystir.com

Any help?

---

Solution: Thanks to  theomega i have solved the isse. Here is the code just for community sharing:

```
$args = array('role' => 'author');

    $authors = get_users($args);
    shuffle($authors);
    $i = 0;
     foreach ($authors as $author): 
           if($i == 4) break;
           //do stuff
           $i++;
         endforeach;
```

Did not set the limit on the $args because i need the shuffle in all users. Hope it will help someone out there, in the wild. :D Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try

```
$users = get_users('ciriteria');
shuffle($users)
//users is now shuffled
```

Using the [PHP Shuffle-Function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.shuffle.php).

Comment: nop its returning false or empty string. It may be not applicable in query results.

Comment: You were right, I edited my anser, shuffle is inplace in php.

Comment: No its not, check the history!

Comment: Oh! got it now :D.. function doesnot return any value just shuffle. It took a while to get in my mind.. thank you!

Answer (score 1):

We can use the `get_users()` to get a list of authors, users with a specific role, user with specific meta, etc. The function returns users which can be ordered by ID, login, nicename, email, url, registered, display_name, post_count, or meta_value. But there is no random option such as what **get_posts()** function provides to shows posts randomly.

Since the `get_users()` function uses `WP_User_Query` class, there is an action hook `pre_user_query` we can use to modify the class variable.

The idea is using our own ‘**rand**’ order by parameter. If we put **rand** to the orderby parameter, “user_login” will be used instead. In this case, we need to replace it with **RAND()** to result users randomly.

In the example below, we I ‘rand’ and you can use your own order by name.

```
add_action( 'pre_user_query', 'my_random_user_query' );

function my_random_user_query( $class ) {
    if( 'rand' == $class->query_vars['orderby'] )
        $class->query_orderby = str_replace( 'user_login', 'RAND()', $class->query_orderby );

    return $class;
}
```

The **WP_User_Query** contains order by query and the our arguments. Now, we have a new order by parameter to WordPress.

```
$users = get_users( array(
    'orderby' => 'rand',
    'number'  => 5
));
print_r( $users );
```

Reference:  http://www.codecheese.com/2014/05/order-wordpress-users-random/

Comment: If I understand how this works, I find this solution superior to the accepted answer, because this will 'shuffle' the results across pagination.

Comment: Actually, this result also randomizes across pagination. You need to set a seed in the Session to avoid that.